# pivot_wider: error message "Error in `vec_init()`: ! `n` must be a single number, not an integer `NA`"

Tags: r, tidyr

I downloaded proteomic data from depmap, and tried to make dataset "depmap_group_id" as rowname and "protein_id" as colname. However, using pivot_wider to create "proteomic_dep_g_ID2" dataset gave me this error message ""Error in `vec_init()`: ! `n` must be a single number, not an integer `NA`".
Is there any solution?
Thank you,

Mei

```
library(depmap)
library(ExperimentHub)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

proteomic_tmp <- depmap_proteomic()
proteomic_dep_g_ID <- proteomic_tmp%>%
  mutate(depmap_group_id=paste0(.$depmap_id,"_",.$group_id))%>%
  select("depmap_group_id","protein_id","protein_expression")

proteomic_dep_g_ID2 <- pivot_wider(proteomic_dep_g_ID , names_from = protein_id, 
                                   values_from = protein_expression, values_fn = mean)
```

Here is proteomic_dep_g_ID looks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjOg5.png)

I have tried to cut down dataset as "0.2 fold size of original dataset", but pivot_wider still gave me this error message "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.4 Gb".

```
ind_0.2<- 0.2*nrow(proteomic_dep_g_ID)
proteomic_dep_g_ID_a<- proteomic_dep_g_ID[1:ind_0.2,]
proteomic_dep_g_ID_a<- proteomic_dep_g_ID_a%>%
  pivot_wider(.,names_from = protein_id, values_from = protein_expression, values_fn = mean)
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example i.e. `dput(head(proteomic_dep_g_ID, 10))`

Comment: You are not using the right syntax for `mutate` - you don't need the `$` notation - just `mutate(depmap_group_id=paste0(depmap_id,"_",group_id))`. It is possible that that was causing unexpected behaviour that might result in the later problem. Nor do you need quotes around the variables in `select`.

Answer (score 0):

There do seem to be other reports of problems with using `values_fn` and very large datasets, so you could try a two-stage approach, such as

```
proteomic_dep_g_ID2 <- proteomic_dep_g_ID %>% 
     group_by(depmap_group_id, protein_id) %>%
     summarise(protein_expression = mean(protein_expression, 
                                         na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  #just in case!
     ungroup() %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = protein_id, 
                 values_from = protein_expression)
```

I don't know if this will work without seeing your data, but it might be worth a try!

Comment: The same errors still exist. Have this error message now: `summarise()` has grouped output by 'depmap_group_id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
Error in `vec_init()`:
! `n` must be a single number, not an integer `NA`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow

Comment: Your `summarise` line needs a closing `)`